# Aligning button groups and text in bootstrap over multiple columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a seemingly simple problem I can fix with a little CSS, but I was wondering if anyone knows of the correct way to lay out in Bootstrap a column with text in it, and then a column with a button in it and getting them vertically aligned.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-8">Looking for something specifc? Have you tried looking through the <a href="#">Topic Index</a>?</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="dropdown dropup pull-right">
  View articles by
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dd-TopicIndex" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Category
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's what it produces:
[image: Misaligned columns]

You see the issue is that the text on the right is aligned to the button, but the text on the left isn't.

Thanks for your help.
D

Answer (score 0):

In fact the btn class add some padding:

```
btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  ...
}
```

The text belongs to the same div so somehow it inherits this padding. So if you want that the text on the left is aligned you may need to add a padding top which is certainly not the best solution.

Comment: This is an easy fix with CSS, but as we both agree not the best. I was hoping that BootStrap may have accounted for such a scenario and there was a native/built in way to achieve this.

Comment: What you could try is to do a [form-inline](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) so it will be aligned.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work when it's split across multiple columns like this. :(

Comment: Damn. I haven't found any clean solution too except adding: position: relative; top: -2px; (or 3px but you got the idea)